# Android SDK Manifest file error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-logcat

I'm a beginner when it comes to both Java and android SDK, and I had some issues that I dealt with to finally be able to run my app, and than I get this error and I just can't figure it out.

So this is the Console:

> [2013-09-17 19:59:23 - AndroidFlow] Installation error:INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
>   [2013-09-17 19:59:23 - AndroidFlow] Please check logcat output for more details.
>   [2013-09-17 19:59:23 - AndroidFlow] Launch canceled!

(Sorry for text fragmentation, it doesn't fit in the same line)

And heres the logcat snap:
[image]

Also, heres the Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.domiq.androidapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:isolatedProcess="false"
    android:label="flow service"
    android:name="com.domiq.androidapp.appservice"
    android:permission="string"
    android:process="string" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.domiq.androidappp"
        android:label="androidapp" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Any suggestions? I've tried a lot of stuff (as you can see nothing is in capital letters etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the future, copy the text out of LogCat (select the lines, press `<Ctrl>-<C>` to copy) rather than use screenshots.

That being said, here are some obvious problems:

1. Your `android:name` in the `<activity>` is invalid, as it does not have the name of your `Activity` class.
2. The one that is causing your error is the `android:process` attribute in the `<service>` element, which is malformed and unnecessary.
3. I am skeptical that the `android:name` in your `<service>` points to a `Service` implementation class.
4. I strongly encourage you to get rid of `android:isolatedProcess` and `android:permission`, as what you have will probably not work the way you expect.

Comment: sorry for the logcat snap :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `Activity`'s name is `com.domiq.androidappp`. This looks to be the `package` name.
So change below line to the Activity class Name. Use the Eclipse Manifest editor rather than adding manually

```
<activity
        android:name="com.domiq.androidappp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the android:permission="string" and android:permission="string". It looks like you just copied pasted that incorrectly. You are supposed to replace "string" with the proper values.

Also your android:name under your Activity should be the Activity name, e.g. android:name="com.domiq.androidapp.MyActivity".